# Basic NumPy data comparison

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array of N-dimensional values arranged in a 2D array. Something like:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.array([[[1,2],[3,4]],[[5,6],[1,2]]])
```

I also have a single value `x` that I want to compare against each data point, and I want to get a 2D array of boolean values showing whether my data is equal to `x`.

```
x = np.array([1,2])
```

If I do:

```
data == x
```

I get

```
# array([[[ True,  True],
#        [False, False]],
#
#       [[False, False],
#        [ True,  True]]], dtype=bool)
```

I could easily combine these to get the result I want. However, I don't want to iterate over each of these slices, especially when `data.shape[2]` is larger. What I am looking for is a direct way of getting:

```
array([[ True,  False],
        [False, True]])
```

Any ideas for this seemingly easy task?

Comment: Hmm.  Just realized that my answer gives a 2-d array as a result, while your question gives a 3-d array as the desired output.  Is that distinction important?

Comment: No that's perfect, thanks. I will amend my desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, `(data == x).all(axis=-1)` gives you what you want.  It's still constructing a 3-d array of results and iterating over it, but at least that iteration isn't at Python-level, so it should be reasonably fast.